# Mysql check for value in mysql database fails?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple use case where I am checking if a certain value is present in the table and it always seems to fail.This is my php code.

```
<?php

            include "config.php";

            $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);

                    if(!$con)
             {
                             echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
             }
             else{
            //echo "";
             }
                     $device_id = $_POST["device_id"];
                     $check = "SELECT magazine_id FROM registered_buyers WHERE device_id = $device_id";
                     $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
                     if(mysqli_num_rows($con,$rs) == 0)
                     {
                     $jsonarray = $_POST["jsonarray"];
                     echo "This will be inserted".$jsonarray;

                     }else
                     {
                            echo "User already registered";
                    }

    ?>
```

Can anyone please point out my mistake.Any help or suggestion is welcome.Thank you.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Check for Errors after executing SQL-statements

Comment: There are no errors Yes I would surely do that but can you point out why it ain't working.@Jens

Comment: Try remove `$con` from `mysqli_num_rows()`- Use only `mysqli_num_rows($rs)` Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Comment: @Dave just did that it is still giving the same result.

Comment: echo the `$query` and `mysqli_error` if any to watch what happens.

Comment: @anup try check if `$_POST["device_id"]` is integer. `var_dump($device_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to follow this code.

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);
if(!$con){
    echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$device_id = $_POST["device_id"];
$check = "SELECT magazine_id FROM registered_buyers WHERE device_id = ".$device_id;
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) == 0){
    $jsonarray = $_POST["jsonarray"];
    echo "This will be inserted".$jsonarray;
}else{
    echo "User already registered";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

since i dont have enough rep to add a comment, i will consider the `device_id` is string, if so try something like this:

```
"SELECT magazine_id FROM registered_buyers WHERE device_id = '$device_id'";
```

add `'`